# Which real values of $\alpha$ is the function $g_{\alpha}(x) = x^{\alpha}\log(x)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

Which real values of $\alpha$ is the function $g_{\alpha}(x) = x^{\alpha}\log(x)$ uniformly continuous?

This is a larger question and through the course of it, I have proven and used a few theorems to take care of the other cases. But there is one case in which I'm not sure if I reasoned things out correctly.

**Attempt**

Case: $0 < \alpha < 1$ on the interval $[1, \infty)$ where $x > y > y_{1} > 1$ Here $y_{1}$ is considered a constant as will be apparent in my proof.

By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists an $x_{*} \in (x,y)$ such that:

\begin{multline}
|f(x) - f(y)|= f'(x_{*})|x-y| = [\alpha (x_{*})^{\alpha - 1} \log(x_{*}) + x_{*}^{\alpha - 1}]|x-y|\\
 <  [\alpha (y_{1})^{\alpha - 1} \log(y_{1}) + y_{1}^{\alpha - 1}]|x-y| = \biggl(\frac{1}{y_{1}^{1-\alpha}}\biggr)(\alpha \log(y_{1}) + 1)|x-y| 
\end{multline}

If we let $$\delta = \frac{y_{1}^{1-\alpha}}{(\alpha  \log(y_{1}) + 1)}$$

Then we would have a satisfactory $\delta$ to establish uniform continuity on $[1,\infty)$.

**Concern:**

My concern revolves around the $y_{1}$ term I introduced. By the properties of Real numbers I know such a number does exist on this interval, but the purpose of uniform continuity is not being dependent on any of these values. Now I am taking the smallest $y_{1}$ and this is a constant, but it feels as if this may not be what I am aiming for. Thoughts ?

**Edit:**

Would the fact that I have shown that my derivative could be bounded by $f'(y_{1})$ then I have established uniform continuity?

Comment: If you were a Calculus I student, how would you find the maximum of $x_*^{\alpha - 1}(1 + \alpha \ln x_*)$?

Comment: uniformly continuous **where**?

Comment: @EricTowers I would take the derivative of my function, find those critical points and then evaluate for the maximum.

Comment: @dc3rd : Happily there is only one critical point (although since you are working over $[1,\infty)$ instead of $(0,\infty)$, you should deal with the endpoint) and the second derivative at that critical point is negative...

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^\alpha \ln x)$.  You wish to bound $|g(x)|$ on $[1,\infty)$.  Since $g(x) > 0$ on $[1,\infty)$, we can drop the absolute value bars.  Happily, $g'(x) = 0$ has one solution on $(0,\infty)$, at $x = \exp \left(\dfrac{1-2\alpha}{\alpha(\alpha - 1)}\right)$, at which $g''$ is negative...

So you find $g(x)$ is bounded by an explicit constant depending only on $\alpha$.

(Carefully doing all the algebra, you will use the fact that $\alpha \in (0,1)$ repeatedly.)

Why this is a problem for your proof:  What happens when $x_*$ lands on this maximum?  Your inequality becomes invalid.  The easiest way to see this is to pick $x$ and $y$ to straddle the maximum so that $f(x) = f(y)$, forcing $x_*$ to the critical point.  But then the expression in $x_*$s is larger than the same expression with any other $y_1$ replacing $x_*$.

Comment: out of curiosity how did you solve for $x$? Because I didin't get anything near that and even reverse engineering what your solution was I don't get that expression. When I took derivative I got: $\alpha x^{\alpha -1}\log(x) + x^{\alpha - 1}$

Comment: @dc3rd : Wait, wait, wait ...  I might be off by one.  Checking...  Nope.  Not off by one.  You mant to extremize $x^{\alpha -1}(1 + \alpha \ln x)$, so you need to take its derivative and set it equal to zero, so yeah, you want $g'(x) = 0$.  $g'(x) = x^{\alpha - 2}\left( 2\alpha -1+ \alpha(\alpha-1) \ln x\right)$.  The first factor is always positive on $[1,\infty)$, so the second factor must give you any zeroes.